# Dynamically updating dash table return empty rows

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I made this small dashboard and I wanted to test a dynamically updating “results table” at the end of the page.
I created these test lines to see how i can update it, but it seems to not update correctly. It shows two additional rows in the output table but it doesnt show any values. When printing out the df the correct values are shown.

It would be great if you can help me.

Cheers,
Mjst

```
button_berechnen = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dcc.Input(
            id="input_marge",
            placeholder= 'marge in 1XX% i.e. 1.4'),
        html.Button('Berechnen', id ='submit-marge', n_clicks = 0),
    ]),
])
#output tabelle
output_table = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
    id = 'output_table',
    columns = [ {'name' : 'Index', 'id': "index"},
                {'name' : 'Produkt', 'id':"produkt"},
                {'name' : 'Ebay', 'id':"ebay"},
                {'name' : 'Amazon', 'id':"amazon"},
                {'name' : 'Real', 'id':"real"},
                {'name' : 'Webshop', 'id':"webshop"}],
    style_cell = {
        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(50,50,50)',
        'color': 'white'

    },
    editable = True
    )
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    button_berechnen,
    output_table,

])


@app.callback(Output('output_table', 'data'),
            Input('submit-marge', 'n_clicks'),
            #Input('produkt_daten', 'data'),
            State('input_marge', 'value'))
#berechnen des output tables
def rows_berechnen(n_clicks, marge):
    if n_clicks >0 :
        df_preise = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'Produkt', 'Ebay', 'Amazon', 'Real', 'Webshop'})
        test = {'Produkt' : 'marge', 'Ebay': marge, 'Amazon': marge, 'Real': marge, 'Webshop': marge}
        test2 = {'Produkt' : 'marge', 'Ebay': marge, 'Amazon': marge, 'Real': marge, 'Webshop': marge}
        df_preise = df_preise.append(test, ignore_index=True)
        df_preise = df_preise.append(test2, ignore_index=True)

        print(df_preise)
        df = df_preise.to_dict(orient ='records')
        return df
    raise PreventUpdate



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `data=[]` in the layout when you define the data table. Sometimes Dash has an issue with properties that haven't been explicitly set.

Edit:
The problem was coming from the way `columns` was defined. I changed it to this, and it worked:

```py
columns=[{'name': 'Index', 'id': "Index"},
                 {'name': 'Produkt', 'id': "Produkt"},
                 {'name': 'Ebay', 'id': "Ebay"},
                 {'name': 'Amazon', 'id': "Amazon"},
                 {'name': 'Real', 'id': "Real"},
                 {'name': 'Webshop', 'id': "Webshop"}],
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt fix the issue.

Comment: I found it. Updated answer for you.

Comment: Thank you now it indeed works. So i guess the dash column ID has to match the column name that you give the df in your callback. Good to know! Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer has fully addressed your question, please click the check to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone tried to have a dynamic table with user inputs for simple arithmetic?

4 = cell[1][1] ; 5 = cell [1][2] ; cell[1][1]+cell[1][2] = cell [1][3]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).